# Need help in building a stopwatch chrome extension using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-api, popup

I am trying to build a stopwatch chrome extension that only starts on certain website domains/URLs. I have figured the whole stopwatch aspect of the project but whenever I close the chrome extension and reopens it, it pull the last place of the stopwatch but then resets to zero. I tried using Chrome's built-in API for memory storage such as chrome.storage.sync.get and chrome.storage.sync.set, but whenever I close the tab it picks up from the last place the timer got stored but then it restarts back at zero and doesn't continue from where the stopwatch was stored. How can I achieve when I click on the extension the stopwatch is still going?

Here is my Javascript:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('time', function(get_time){
if (get_time.time) {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = get_time.time;
}
});

let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;

function stopWatch() {

seconds++;

if (seconds / 60 === 1) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;

    if (minutes / 60 === 1) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;
    }
}

if (seconds < 10) {
    displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
} else {
    displaySeconds = seconds;
}

if (minutes < 10) {
    displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
} else {
    displayMinutes = minutes;
}

if (hours < 10) {
    displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
} else {
    displayHours = hours;
}

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
var time = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
chrome.storage.sync.set({'time': time});

}

window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Comment: I already have a background script running that allows the chrome extension to work on certain URLs. I need the stopwatch to continually run even when the popup is not there but it is allowed on the URL page.

Answer (score 0):

When the popup page is closed all javascript related to it will also be terminated.
You need to move the functions and storage setter to your background script.